# Given a positive integer n show that there exists one and only one pair of integers h and k with 0 ≤ h < k such that n = 1/2 k(k − 1) + h.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $n$ show that there exists one and only one pair of
integers $h$ and $k$ with $0 \leq h < k$ such that $n = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}+h$.

I don't really know how to approach this problem.  This is help I was given from another site but it doesn't make sense to me:

Given a positive integer $n$, we can always find a integer k such that

$1+2+3+\cdots+(k-1)<=n<1+2+3+\cdots+k$

for such $k$ , $h =n-(1+2+....+(k-1))=n-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$

Clearly,$0\leq h<k$

Now, suppose there exists another integer $x$ different from k such that $n=\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+y$,$0<=y<x$

Clearly, $x<k$ as $1+2+3+\cdots+k>n$

So, $y=n-\frac{x(x-1)}{2}\geq n-(1+2+3+\cdots+(k-2)) \geq1+2+\cdots+(k-1)-(1+2+3+\cdots+(k-2)\geq k-1>x$

this is a contradiction as $y<x$

So, there exists just one pair of $h$ and $k$ such that $n=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+h$

Comment: What doesn't make sense?This seems pretty clear.

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you typeset you question with TeX.

Comment: This question is not about mathematical logic, so I retagged it.

Comment: The part that confuses me is how is it clear that x<k. Can someone explain that part?

Comment: Thank you for re-tagging, wasn't sure what to tag.

Answer (score 1):

The proof starts by stating the fact that for any integer $n \ge 1$, we can always find an integer $k \ge 2$ satisfying
$$\frac{k(k-1)}{2} \le n < \frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$ By this definition (*i.e.*, that $n$ lies between two consecutive triangular numbers, possibly equal to the lesser), there obviously can be no integer $x$ such that
$$\frac{k(k-1)}{2} < \frac{x(x-1)}{2} \le n.$$
Hence, when the proof later assumes the existence of “another integer […] different from $k$”, it must be smaller than $k$ (because if it was larger, then $x(x-1)/2 > n$).

Comment: This can be viewed as a generalization to the fact that there is no integer $n$ such that $ x^2<n^<(x+1)^2 $. Similarly, for triangle numbers, taking advantage of the discreet structure.